# How to create a script that clicks on all follow buttons on a behance page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

How does one go about this ? Behance has  discover pages and follower pages, that may contain  a few thousand users. Each user has a follow button. Clicking each one individually is crazy.

This is the button in case that helps.

```
<a class="form-button form-button-follow form-button-small form-button-default form-button-left-icon form-button-icon-follow">
   Follow  
</a>
```

Comment: Depends on what is behind the click event. But you could try `$('.form-button-follow').click()`. Don't know if it will work.

Comment: @putvande This works but buttons that already clicked, are being unclicked. is there a way to do an if else ? This is what shows up when I say inspect element (not clicked yet) Follow button : a class="form-button form-button-follow form-button-small form-button-default form-button-left-icon form-button-icon-follow">Follow</a> (already clicked) Following button : a class="form-button form-button-following form-button-small form-button-light-and-grey form-button-left-icon form-button-icon-following">Following</a>

Comment: But it looks like the button for people who are already following doesn't have the class `form-button-follow` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$( '.form-button-follow' ).click ();
```

It trigger a click event on selected elements.

[More](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: How would one be able to run this on a wbpage like behance. I want to log in, open a list of people to follow and then have the statement you just gave me, run a few hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

If the links are handled with javascript and submit ajax requests then you can just manually trigger a click on all of them like so:

```
$('.form-button-icon-follow').click();
```

However, if these follow links do a full postback (page refreshes) then this will not work as it will refresh the page as soon as the first link is 'clicked'. In that case you might need to see what data is actually posted to the server and you might be able to create your own ajax requests to use instead.

Comment: How would one be able to run this on a wbpage like behance. I want to log in, open a list of people to follow and then have the statement you just gave me, run a few hundred times.

Comment: Open it in chrome and go to the page you want, then press F12 to open up the developer tools and paste that code into the console and press enter. Note that their site probably will not have been designed to work like this so it possibly wont work.

Comment: This works but buttons that already clicked, are being unclicked. is there a way to do an if else ?
This is what shows up when I say inspect element
(not clicked yet) Follow button : a class="form-button form-button-follow form-button-small form-button-default form-button-left-icon form-button-icon-follow">Follow</a>

(already clicked) Following button : 
a class="form-button form-button-following form-button-small form-button-light-and-grey form-button-left-icon form-button-icon-following">Following</a>

Comment: @user1283103 I've updated the script to use the 'form-button-icon-follow' class instead. Try that.

Comment: where can I learn this stuff form. And is this java script or jquery or both ?

Comment: jQuery is javascript. This is jQuery code, you can start from http://learn.jquery.com/